# Ionic: how to hide ion slide pager on first slide

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework, slider

how can i hide ion slide pager only on the first slide? My code is something like:

```
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="item in lista_tutorial[0].lista_slide">
 <div ng-if="item.tipo == 'benvenuto'" class="divBenvenutoTreVeline">
   ABC
 </div>
 <div ng-if="item.tipo == 'home'" class="divBenvenutoTreVeline">
   BCD
 </div>
<ion-slide-page>
```

So I have 2 slides but only one tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<ion-slides [pager]="!isFirstSlide()">
```

with

```
isFirstSlide(){
   return this.yourSlides.isBeginning();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-if="$first"**

```
<ion-slide-page ng-repeat="item in lista_tutorial[0].lista_slide" ng-if="!$first">
 <div ng-if="item.tipo == 'benvenuto'" class="divBenvenutoTreVeline">
   ABC
 </div>
 <div ng-if="item.tipo == 'home'" class="divBenvenutoTreVeline">
   BCD
 </div>
<ion-slide-page>
```

Comment: Nah, i want to remove my swiper pagination (the bullets) on the first slide because i have a "start" button in that...so I don't need bullets...sorry for the mistake. Can u help?

Comment: @Jamil89 I don't be sure why are you doing that but you can hide the slider pagination in the <ion-slides> settings.

In the next link you have an example in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRoGJB